# How does a Tiki Torch differ from a standard Torch?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria 1.0.6 Tiki Torches have been added, which can be crafted using a torch + 3 wood.

How exactly do they differ from the standard torches?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The main difference between the Tiki Torch and the regular Torch is that the Tiki Torch cannot be held in your hand and carried. You have to place it on the ground to use it.

As you can see from these screenshots, they give off the same level of luminescence.

[image: Regular Torch]
[image: Tiki Torch]

Comment: I kinda fail to see the point of them then, apart perhaps from aesthetics.

Comment: @Thomas I think the point is aesthetics, yeah. They added a bunch of decorative items in 1.0.6 that have no other function other than to look pretty, like the [Dresser](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Dresser) and the [Toilet](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Toilet).

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes That's not their only use. They can replace the Table and Chair for NPC houses, respectively. The Tiki Torch is also a valid light source.

Comment: @lunboks True! I was thinking of functionality in regards to a direct benefit to the player, such as say the Dressers providing a storage space or something, which they don't. Though it is nice, flavor-wise, that you can put a bed or something for the NPC and have it count.

Comment: Aside from your pictures having the opposite captions, it shows that the tiki torch has a slightly larger illuminated area as well.

Comment: @Raven The labels got switched when Brant edited them, I fixed that. Regarding the light level, Thomas and I were discussing this earlier on chat. If you look closely, the luminescence levels are the same, however the light from the Tiki has a higher point of origin because it's a couple blocks off of the ground, so it creates the illusion the the level of light is different. Look at the row 5 blocks down beneath where I am standing. You can see that with the regular torch, it's ever so slightly lighter than with the Tiki because of the elevation difference.

Comment: @Raven It's actually the same, if not slightly less. The reason is simply because it's off the ground, instead of being directly on it like the other torch.

Comment: I can confirm they're the same. Both have the exact light value of `1f`.

Comment: @Xkeeper - Ah, yes. That makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

According to the official Terraria wiki, [it cannot be held like a normal torch.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tiki_Torch)

Answer (score 5):

Besides not being able to hold a tiki torch, there is another difference. Tiki torches can be placed on wooden platforms, regular torches can't.

Answer (score 3):

You can place tiki torches on wooden platforms, which you cannot do with normal torches. I found this helpful when fighting bosses at night.